# Google Maps Web (Nov 2017 New UI) Marker Icons

Tags: google-maps-markers

See the new 'flat' styled marker icons in *Google Maps Web*.

Anyone know where I can get a link to the image resources? I'm doing some custom Google Maps web work and want to use the new icons now.

[image: Google Maps Web (New UI Nov 2017)]

Answer (score 6):

Ok so found the answer by inspecting the new Google Maps web and using their assets:

```
var imageBlue = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/blue-dot.png';
  var imageRed = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png';
  var imageGreen = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/green-dot.png';
  var imageLtBlue = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/ltblue-dot.png';
  var imageYellow = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/yellow-dot.png';
  var imagePurple = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/purple-dot.png';
  var imagePink = 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/pink-dot.png';
  // Custom images below taken from source images URLs of new Google Maps
  // Can change HEX color values, scale=1 is small, scale=2 is bigger, scale=3 is biggest
  var scale = 1;
  var imageCustomPinSpotlight = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/spotlight/spotlight_pin_v2_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/spotlight/spotlight_pin_v2-1-small.png,assets/icons/spotlight/spotlight_pin_v2_dot-1-small.png,assets/icons/spotlight/spotlight_pin_v2_accent-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,ea4335,960a0a,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomAirport = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/airport_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,10bdff,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomHospital = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/hospital_H_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,f88181,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomHospitalLite = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/hospital_H_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,F5AFAF,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomDotLtGreen = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/dot_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,4db546,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomDotRCBSRed = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/dot_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,E42313,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomStar = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_outline-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/constellation_star_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,ffffff,fbc02d,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomHeart = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_outline-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/heart_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,ffffff,fa507d,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomFlag = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_shadow-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_outline-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/nickname_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ff000000,ffffff,4285f4,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
  var imageCustomHome = 'https://www.google.com.au/maps/vt/icon/name=assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet_outline-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/tactile/pinlet-1-small.png,assets/icons/poi/quantum/pinlet/home_pinlet-1-small.png&highlight=ffffff,4285f4,ffffff&color=ff000000?scale=' + scale;
```

Comment: scale=4 is the biggest :)

Comment: Great list! Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to modify the URL parameters on the `imageCustomPinSpotlight` to create a blue variant?